# Extend controller - but how activate it? (Symfony 2)

Tags: php, symfony

I want to use this code in my application:

```
class ControllerExtension extends Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller 
{
    public function render($view, array $parameters = array(), Response $response = null)
    {

        //etc.

    }

}
```

But where do I put it and how do i activate it? I'm guessing it's something to do with the services.yml file. I've used Event Listeners, but this is obviously different.

Answer (score 2):

From your code snippet (http://justpaste.it/2caz), it seems that you missed the "return" keyword in your call to parent.

```
class ControllerExtension extends Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller 
{
    public function render($view, array $parameters = array(), Response $response = null)
    {
        if($this->getRequest()->getRequestFormat() == 'json') {
            return new Response(json_encode($parameters));
        } else {
            // Missing 'return' in your snippet
            return parent::render($view, $parameters, $response);
        }
    }

}

class MyController extends ControllerExtension
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // This should now work
        return $this->render(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in your bundle's Controller directory i.e `src/YourNamespace/YourBundleName/Controller/ControllerExtension.php`.
Make sure you provide the appropriate namespace in that file:

```
namespace YourNamespace\YourBundleName\Controller;
class ControllerExtension extends Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller
{
...
```

To use it, either create a route for it in `src/YourNamespace/YourBundlename/Resources/config/routing.yml`

or

extend it:

```
namespace YourNamespace\YourBundleName\Controller;
class OtherController extends ControllerExtension
{
...
```

If what you are actually looking to do is override another bundle's controller, see the cookbook which describes [overriding controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html).

*Edit*:

As far as I know, there's no way to automatically make this controller somehow take effect. You can have each of your controllers extend it as I've indicated above.

You might be able to [create an event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) and use the [response event](http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/KernelEvents.html) to somehow change the response if the format is json. But, I'm not sure how you would access the view data from the event listener.

Comment: Hi thanks, but I'm still struggling to get this to work. Basically I just want to override 'every single' controller in the project. It would only perform a small action. Just like I have activated a Request Listener in services.yml which runs on every request, I want this to run on every request, but I can't get it to run.

Comment: You might want to update your question with more specifics...what exactly you want to run on every request. There may be an easier way than with a controller class.

Comment: Something like this: http://justpaste.it/2caz - I just can't get the code to run (to pick up the class)

Comment: Is the what you want to do: render a json response if the requested format is json, otherwise render html via the twig template?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do, but I can't see where to put the code (to activate it, so to speak).